# How to do full outer join to combine two tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join, full-outer-join

I have two tables **payroll_advance** and **payroll_advrtn**,and i supposed to do full outer join to get my require result.But,I'm sure full outer join isn't possible in mysql and also i know that full outer join is possible by using the union.But i don't know how can i do join at the following query.

My **payroll_advance** table produce the following result.

```
SELECT _id,_tid,_dt,sum(_amount) as _advance FROM payroll_advance WHERE YEAR( _dt )=YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(_dt) = MONTH(CURDATE()) group by _tid;

+-----+-------+------------+---------+
| _id | _tid  | _dt        | _advance|
+-----+-------+------------+---------+
|  17 | hjg   | 2012-04-18 |    2151 |
|  22 | RKT01 | 2012-04-10 |    2098 |
|  14 | RKT04 | 2012-04-18 |    1511 |
|  16 | RKT09 | 2012-04-09 |     250 |
|  15 | RKT10 | 2012-04-17 |    1313 |
|   8 | RKT21 | 2012-04-03 |    1321 |
|  19 | RKT31 | 2012-04-26 |    2512 |
|  20 | RKT33 | 2012-04-10 |    2250 |
|  25 | T01   | 2012-04-11 |    2500 |
+-----+-------+------------+---------+
```

And payroll_advrtn gives the following result.

```
SELECT _id,_tid,_dt,sum(_amount) as _advrtn FROM payroll_advrtn WHERE YEAR( _dt ) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(_dt) = MONTH(CURDATE()) group by _tid;
+-----+-------+------------+---------+
| _id | _tid  | _dt        | _advrtn |
+-----+-------+------------+---------+
|   9 | RKT02 | 2012-04-10 |    2500 |
|   8 | RKT04 | 2012-04-20 |     150 |
+-----+-------+------------+---------+
```

But i want something like the following result by combining the above two result.

```
 +------+-------+-------+------------+----------+---------+
| _id  | _tid  | _tid  | _dt        | _advance | _advrtn |
+------+-------+-------+------------+----------+---------+
|   17 | hjg   | NULL  | 2012-04-18 |     2151 |    NULL |
|   22 | RKT01 | NULL  | 2012-04-10 |      999 |    NULL |
|   14 | RKT04 | RKT04 | 2012-04-18 |       11 |     150 |
|   16 | RKT09 | NULL  | 2012-04-09 |      250 |    NULL |
|   15 | RKT10 | NULL  | 2012-04-17 |     1313 |    NULL |
|    8 | RKT21 | NULL  | 2012-04-03 |     1321 |    NULL |
|   19 | RKT31 | NULL  | 2012-04-26 |     2512 |    NULL |
|   20 | RKT33 | NULL  | 2012-04-10 |     2250 |    NULL |
|   25 | T01   | NULL  | 2012-04-11 |     2500 |    NULL |
| NULL | NULL  | RKT02 | NULL       |     NULL |    2500 |
+------+-------+-------+------------+----------+---------+
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks!!

Comment: Your result does not look like a FULL JOIN.

Comment: @ypercube: Yes, it doesn't look like anything in particular, but I presume that Op might have made some mistakes while producing the deisred result. I provided an answer giving the `FULL OUTER JOIN` results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do the `FULL OUTER JOIN` [you can do](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/) the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `UNION` with `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` (<strike>provided that `MySql` still does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN`</strike>):

```
select * from A as a
    left outer join B as b on a.col = b.col
union
select * from A as a
    right outer join B as b on a.col = b.col
```

Note that you can use subqueries for `A` and `B` - which should work with your queries. In your case:

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM t1) as a
    left outer join (SELECT * FROM t2) as b on a._tid = b._tid
union
select * from (SELECT * FROM t1) as a
    right outer join (SELECT * FROM t2) as b on a._tid = b._tid
```

With result being equal to (provided that I didn't my a mistake in copy-pasting your data):

```
+------+-------+------------+----------+------+-------+------------+----------+
| _id  | _tid  | _dt        | _advance | _id  | _tid  | _dt        | _advartn |
+------+-------+------------+----------+------+-------+------------+----------+
|   17 | hjg   | 2012-04-18 |     2151 | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |     NULL |
|   22 | RKT01 | 2012-04-10 |     2098 | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |     NULL |
|   14 | RKT04 | 2012-04-18 |     1511 |    8 | RKT04 | 2012-04-20 |      150 |
|   16 | RKT09 | 2012-04-09 |      250 | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |     NULL |
|   15 | RKT10 | 2012-04-17 |     1313 | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |     NULL |
|    8 | RKT21 | 2012-04-03 |     1321 | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |     NULL |
|   19 | RKT31 | 2012-04-26 |     2512 | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |     NULL |
|   20 | RKT33 | 2012-04-10 |     2250 | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |     NULL |
|   25 | T01   | 2012-04-11 |     2500 | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |     NULL |
| NULL | NULL  | NULL       |     NULL |    9 | RKT02 | 2012-04-10 |     2500 |
+------+-------+------------+----------+------+-------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But,how can i filter the result by date constraint i.e only display the current month's data.

Comment: For example add a date restriction (e.g. `BETWEEN`) to the queries in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: When i'm trying to give the field list instead of '*' for the above given query i'm getting the following error "#1052 - Column 'my column name' in field list is ambiguous".Can i get the selected field?

Comment: When more than one table is used (in a `JOIN` for example) there may be two columns with the same name. You need to use aliases, as I did in the answer (e.g. `a._tid`)

Comment: Done.Thanks @Anonymous for spending your valuable time and solving my problem.marked as accepted answer:)

Comment: Won't work. This will result in the same ERROR 1137 (Can't reopen table) as mentioned in the comment from Joe in golimar's answer.

Comment: @physicalattraction [Oh... really?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3af7b5/3).  Fix your stuff first.

Comment: I see what went wrong. In my case, the tables a and b were 'temporary' Tables. In that case, this won't work, you will get ERROR 1137. If they are normal Tables, this will work. Perhaps you can clarify this in the answer?

Comment: @physicalattraction: The word *temporary* does not appear in the question or my answer - thus I don't see a need for clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Store the results of both queries like this:

```
create temporary table a as select ... ;
create temporary table b as select ... ;
```

Then:

```
select * from a left join b using (_tid)
union
select * from a right join b using (_tid);
```

Comment: It's wrong answer. I guess you haven't tested it. It won't work, because the result will be: `ERROR 1137 (HY000): Can't reopen table: 'a'`. Table a will be locked.