# Where is the error in my full outer join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and am wondering what is wrong in my syntax or logic here. I have my own table `clients` like

```
id   |  name      |  postid  |  sord  |
--------------------------------------------------------
1       Paul Allen   19         1
2       McDermot     8          2
```

and the `postid` column in that table is referring to the same thing as the `id` column in the `wp_posts` table like

```
id | ... | ... |           guid            | ... 
--------------------------------------------------
1   ...    ...     images/somepic.jpg        ... 
.
.
8   ...    ...     images/mypic.gif          ... 
.
.
.
19   ...   ...     images/thatpic.png        ...
.
.
.
```

What I want to return is a table of rows like

```
id   |  name      |  postid  |  sord  |   guid 
--------------------------------------------------------
1       Paul Allen   19         1         images/mypic.gif
2       McDermot     8          2         images/thatpic.png
```

so that I have the corresponding image paths that I can use to build out my page. I believe the method for this scenario is a full outer join. My PHP is like

```
global $wpdb;
$allCients = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT clients.id, clients.name, clients.postid, clients.sord, wp_posts.guid 
    FROM clients 
    FULL OUTER JOIN wp_posts
    ON clients.postid=wp_posts.id
    ORDER BY clients.sord
");

$numClients = count($allCients);
```

but for some reason that is returning 0 results (i.e. `$numClients` is `0`) instead of the expected 2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you expect 2 rows to be returned, try `inner join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not support `full outer join`.  But you don't need it anyway, if you have a proper foreign key relationship.  For instance, if you want all clients, even those without posts:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.postid, c.sord, p.guid 
FROM clients c LEFT JOIN
     wp_posts p
     ON c.postid = p.id
ORDER BY c.sord;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL, there is no `FULL OUTER JOIN`. What you can do instead is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, a `UNION` and a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. This stack overflow answer has an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10137216/4629105

```
select * from A as a
    left outer join B as b on a.col = b.col
union
select * from A as a
    right outer join B as b on a.col = b.col
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to do a `LEFT JOIN` in this case.

Simply take out the `FULL OUTER` like other mentioned.

So your code would be:

```
global $wpdb;
$allCients = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT clients.id, clients.name, clients.postid, clients.sord, wp_posts.guid 
    FROM clients 
    JOIN wp_posts
    ON clients.postid=wp_posts.id
    ORDER BY clients.sord
");

$numClients = count($allCients);
```